# sh: 1: laravel: not found while laravel command works

Tags: php, linux, laravel, path

I'm having trouble installing Laravel Spark. When I run `spark new website` I get the error `sh: 1: laravel: not found`. I read on the internet that this problem is usually caused by incorrect configuration of `$PATH` but this is not the case for me. I have `composer global require laravel/installer` and `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin` has been added to my `$PATH`. When I type `laravel` in the terminal it simply works and I can make new Laravel websites.

I've also cloned the `laravel/spark-installer` repo and added it to my path and typing `spark` in the terminal also works.

The output I'm getting when I'm trying to create a new spark website is the following:

```
git@staging:~$ spark new sparktest
sh: 1: laravel: not found
Downloading Spark...
PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(/home/git/sparktest/spark-archive.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/git/spark/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 59
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/git/spark/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 105
PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in /home/git/spark/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 107
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/git/spark/src/Installation/DownloadSpark.php on line 120
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/git/sparktest/composer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/git/spark/src/Installation/UpdateComposerFile.php on line 54
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: @TomLord "_When I type laravel in the terminal it simply works and I can make new Laravel websites._" Yes, typing laravel works. Question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Whoops sorry, misread that. I'll delete the above.

Comment: @TomLord no problem :)  other ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about these technologies, so won't be posting an answer here. However, my guess is that `spark` runs in a different environment to your login shell, where the `$PATH` is missing the `laravel` executable. Here's what I'd personally do to try debugging this:

Comment: 1. Restart the machine. Does it now work? If not, does running `laravel` directly still work? 2. Find where the error *"sh: 1: laravel: not found"* originates from. Print the `$PATH` from within this script. Is it different to your login shell's `$PATH`? Where does it get defined?

Comment: @TomLord Rebooting didn't help unfortunately. Where $PATH is defined in the script is a good question. It's actually PHP: laravel/spark-installer on Github. My $PATH is: `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/home/git/spark:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: Can you find where *"sh: 1: laravel: not found"* originates from? What is the result of typing `which laravel`?

Comment: @TomLord I'm pretty sure it's caused by the symfony\console package somewhere.This is a pretty massive library so I don't know exactly where. It's registered in src/Installation/CreateLaravelProject.php

Comment: @TomLord The `which` thing is weird as well because it doesn't actually print anything.. Even though the `laravel` command does work.

Comment: @TomLord I found the solution! Probably a beginners mistake. In my bashrc I added `$PATH=~/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` (location of the laravel bin) but apparently it only works when I write it as `$PATH=/home/$USER/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH`! Thank you for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

The PATH for Laravel should be: `~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer"` instead of `~/.config/composer/vendor/bin` ...

Add a line to `~./bash_profile` like:

`export PATH="$PATH:~/.composer/vendor/laravel/installer"`

Close and start a new shell, and enter:

`$ laravel --version
Laravel Installer 2.0.1`